# I want to update the app version in playstore to show a message dialog to user

Tags: flutter

I am new flutter .I want to update new version app in playstore to show a message dialog to user to update the new version and I used the plugin version_check 0.2.0.
When the user has already updated, but it still displays Message dialog the same. How not to show message dialog after update.Who can help me?

[This my Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfEIN.png)

[This my Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju0YQ.png)

[This my Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UstYL.png)

Comment: We need more details. Please see [ask] with [mcve]

Comment: I think you should show more details, maybe some code or the pubspec file, so people could help you.

Answer (score 1):

As everything is not clear in the question, you should follow given steps to achieve the same.

***Step 1. Go to Remote Config in firebase and add few parameters shown in the image and then publish it.***[image]

***Step 2. Create a function VersionCheck and _showVersionDialog as follows:***

```
versionCheck(){
    //Get Current installed version of app

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      final PackageInfo info = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
      double currentVersion = double.parse(info.version.trim().replaceAll(".", ""));

      //Get Latest version info from firebase config
      final RemoteConfig remoteConfig = await RemoteConfig.instance;

      try {
        // Using default duration to force fetching from remote server.
        await remoteConfig.fetch(expiration: const Duration(seconds: 0));
        await remoteConfig.activateFetched();
        remoteConfig.getString('force_update_current_version');

        double newVersion = double.parse(remoteConfig
            .getString('force_update_current_version')
            .trim()
            .replaceAll(".", ""));
        if (newVersion > currentVersion) {
          setState(() {
            versionCode =  remoteConfig.getString('force_update_current_version');
            aboutVersion =  remoteConfig.getString('update_feature');
          });
          _showVersionDialog(context);
        }
      } on FetchThrottledException catch (exception) {
        // Fetch throttled.
        print(exception);
      } catch (exception) {
        print('Unable to fetch remote config. Cached or default values will be '
            'used');
      }

    });

  }
```

```
_showVersionDialog(context) async {
    await showDialog<String>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        String title = "Update Available";
        String message =
            "About Update: \n";

        return ButtonBarTheme(
          data:   ButtonBarThemeData(alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center),
          child: new AlertDialog(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
            title: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(title),
                Text("v"+versionCode),
              ],
            ),
            content: Container(
              height: 80,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(message,style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                  Text(aboutVersion),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: new Text(
                    'Update',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  color: Color(0xFF121A21),
                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _launchURL(PLAY_STORE_URL);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

***Step 3. Call VersionCheck in init function of your main screen as follows.***

```
  @override
  void initState() {
  
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 5000), () {


       if(mounted){
         setState(() {
           versionCheck();
         });
       }

    });

    super.initState();

  }
```

***Step 4. Whenever you want the update dialog to appear on screen just increase the version code value in remote config of firebase than your actual version code value.***

This will help you to achieve what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have video.

Comment: bro now Error versionCheck(); in main .How to fix it?

Comment: Can you please attach the screenshot of error?

Comment: Thank bro now it fixed

Comment: Do you mind giving upvote and check correct to the answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

this is really very easy to do.
There is a package which makes this really very easy:- https://pub.dev/packages/playstore_update

Using this package you can directly show a pop up to a user whenever there is a new update of your app on Google Play Store.

At the same time if you don't want the popup but just want the details of the version of your app or the app available on play store, you can refer these packages:-

https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus

https://pub.dev/packages/peekanapp